# scroll-padding-top not working when anchor referenced from another page

Tags: html, css

I have a standard CSS set up to manage Jump To links within a page:

```
html {
   scroll-padding-top: 150px;
}
```

This works great when I am linking to something within the page.  However, if I link to another page, the anchor goes to top (default), which then hides behind my fixed header.

In both cases the url displays:

```
site.com/#link
```

What may be causing this and how can I resolve it?

Comment: What about if you also add:  scroll-behavior: smooth; ??

Comment: @cesar - that oddly quickly goes to the correct heading, then slowly finishes the scroll going to top.